# Parameter not being passed in to procedure

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, procedure, spring-jdbc

I'm having trouble calling procedure in mssql server using java.
I keep getting org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException

Here is my code:

```
    public void init(@Qualifier("mssqlDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
        this.findBgNumber = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
            .withProcedureName(".sp_GetMaybeBGnumberKT")
            .withCatalogName("dbVilluleit")
            .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("@KT", java.sql.Types.VARCHAR))
            .returningResultSet("bgNumber", new BgRowMapper());
    }

    public List<BgcNumber> getBGNumber(String kennitala) {
        SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
        .addValue("@KT", kennitala, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        Map<String, Object> results = findBgNumber.execute(in);
        List<BgcNumber> list = (List<BgcNumber>) results.get("bgNumber");
        return list;
    }
```

The stacktrace says that '@KT' is not supplied but that is not right.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

This is the stacktrace

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call dbVilluleit..sp_GetMaybeBGnumberKT()}]; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Procedure or function 'sp_GetMaybeBGnumberKT' expects parameter '@KT', which was not supplied.
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:97)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:952)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:985)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:368)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:342)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:164)
at is.siminn.centrex.data.BgcDataGatewayImpl.getBGNumber(BgcDataGatewayImpl.java:73)
at is.siminn.centrex.service.BgcInfoServiceImpl.getBgcInfo(BgcInfoServiceImpl.java:55)
at is.siminn.centrex.ws.BgcImpl.getBgc(BgcImpl.java:30)
at is.siminn.centrex.ws.BgcTestInt.testGetBGC(BgcTestInt.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringTestMethod.invoke(SpringTestMethod.java:160)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTestMethod(SpringMethodRoadie.java:233)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie$RunBeforesThenTestThenAfters.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:333)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runWithRepetitions(SpringMethodRoadie.java:217)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTest(SpringMethodRoadie.java:197)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:143)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:160)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Procedure or function 'sp_GetMaybeBGnumberKT' expects parameter '@KT', which was not supplied.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1493)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:390)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:340)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4575)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:179)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:154)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:322)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$5.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:987)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:936)
... 31 more
```

Thanks

Gunnlaugur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call 'declareParameters' for your 'SimpleJdbcCall'

Comment: I added .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("@KT", java.sql.Types.VARCHAR)) but I get the same exception

Comment: Any idea what might possibly be causing my problem?

Comment: I solved the problem by adding call to withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess

Comment: I searched for a couple days for an answer to this problem, with no help - the comment mentioning 'withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess' needs to be its own answer and it NEEDS to have at least five thousand upvotes.  Possibly ten thousand.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error message, but the actual problem was that .withSchemaName was not specified.